# How can I configure quic/http3 over spring-cloud-starter-function-web?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor-netty, spring-cloud-function

I will try use spring-cloud-starter-function-web with quic/http3.
How can I cofigure quic/http3 server?